# remove automatic spacing to fill row

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I'm writing my thesis, but I have a problem that I can not solve.
Latex when there are few words in a stripe, adds spaces to completely fill the line.

[image]

How can I remove the spaces to fill the line?
NB: I'm using book documentclass.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us -- as usual here -- a short compilable tex code resulting in your shown screenshot ...

Comment: Welcome between the users of TeX.SE. Your complete code is important; it could probably be a hyphenation problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\linebreak`. If the text should continue in a new line, try `\newline` or better an empty line:

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}

or a predicate vertex\linebreak
bla bla

or a predicate vertex\newline
bla bla

or a predicate vertex

bla bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was just that!